# Material Ui Table Row hover and selected color change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

The color and background css property change in material ui table row and column works something like.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  row: {
    cursor: "pointer",
  },
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: "red !important",
    color: " #fff !important",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "transparent !important",
    },
  },
  hover: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "green !important",
      color: " #fff !important",
    },
  },
  column: {
    color: "inherit !important",
  },
}));

  <TableRow
     hover
     selected
     classes={{
       root: classes.row,
       hover: classes.hover,
       selected: classes.selected,}}
     >
       <TableCell classes={{ root: classes.column }}/>
  </TableRow>
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please revise to do so.